# Borland socket server, what is that?

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-6

This is not question about programming, but I think maybe I'll get some answers here.
Probably some of you did work with this and you can tell me more about it.

So, on a client we need to install some weird old SW written in D6 which needs Borland socket server installed on our server. Problem is that I don't know how and If it's even possible to run this Borland socket server as a service. 
And when you start this application on client it also opens an empy GUI form on server :S

So what exactly is Borland socket server and is it possible to run it as a service ?

Best regards, primoz

Comment: A Google search on "Borland Socket Server" returned 42000 results from Google in 0.19 seconds. The first dozen look like they would answer your question.

Comment: The reason I mention a Google search, BTW, is that you're already aware your question is off-topic here.

Comment: I checked on google first and read quite a few results but there was no answer to my questions.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Socket_Connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is a DCOM proxy which allows Datasnap servers to be used by clients without the need to connect directly via DCOM (it is more firewall friendly, and less complex to setup. In turn many of the DCOM security features are lost
2. It can be run as a service. Execute it once with the -install command line option, and then you'll find it in the service manager.
3. When a client connects, the server may display a simple window, if it is not written to hide somehow the server application DCOM istantiates.

Comment: What happens if this runs as service and there is no user logged on to computer ? Does is crashes or just don't show up window.

Comment: @Primoz You need to spend some time to learn about how services run. The entire point of a service is that it runs when there is no user logged on and that it operates without UI.

Comment: @David I know that. 
But when client starts his aplication the window shows on server. So I want to know what happens if this runs as a service and it cannot show window. Does it crash then ?

Comment: @Primoz, just try and come with the results... I don't find how you think a program can be installed as a service just to crash the first time it is used without giving it a try...

Comment: Service may display Windows in a separate desktop, but as long as they are windows that don't require user interaction that's not an issue.